# Call to undefined function Form() using laravel 5.2

Tags: php, forms, laravel, laravel-5, reset-password

when i go to my view, following error occurs:

> FatalErrorException in 9edd5e400844b5418c6227c302e89f04657fb615.php line 3:
>   Call to undefined function Form()

my view file :

```
{!!Form::open(array('url'=>'resetpwd','method'=>'PUT')) ;!!}
 <p>{!!Form(password('password'));!!}</p>
 {!!$errors->first('password');!!}
 {!!Form::hidden('code',$code);!!}
 <p> {!!Form::submit('Reset Passsword');!!} </p>
 {!!Form::close();!!}
 {!!$errors->first('reseterror');!!}
```

Comment: Have you installed and configured the package correctly? As the `Form` facade no longer comes stock standard with Laravel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you have installed **[Laravel Recepie](http://laravel-recipes.com).** You do not declare `Form::password()` method correctly.Edit your code with below changes hope it will be helped you.**[See](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/156/creating-a-password-input-field)** how to use this method in Laravel Recepie.
Change `{!!Form(password('password'));!!}` to `{!!Form::password('password');!!}`

Answer (score 0):

Form does not come as part of core component so you need to add it to laravel.
For that you need to edit the composer.json file found in the laravel main diretory.
Change this line

```
 "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.2.*"
    },
```

TO

```
 "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
        "laravelcollective/html": "5.2.*"
    },
```

Then run `composer update` in your terminal. It will add all the collectives which includes forms.

next you have to add your new provider to the providers array of config/app.php.

You will find this in your app.php

```
 'providers' => [

        /*
         * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
         */
        Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider::class,
        ....................
```

NEED TO ADD THE LINE `Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,`
**SO Change Providers to**

```
Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider::class,
        Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class, ....
```

Last step is to add two class aliases to the aliases array of config/app.php

```
 'aliases' => [

        'App' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::class,
        'Artisan' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::class,
        'Auth' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::class,...
```

ADD The extra two classes FORM,HTML there

```
 'App' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::class,
    'Artisan' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::class,
    'Auth' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::class,
    'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
    'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,...
```

Now you can use the form in laravel.

Ref: https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html